# Mode expansion of the field operator in non-relativistic QFT

Tags: quantum-field-theory, operators, fourier-transform

Following [David Tong's notes](http://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/tong/qft/two.pdf), in eq. (2.111) he claims that for a non-relativistic field operator the Fourier expansion is as given. It makes intuitive sense, but how can one argue formally that, as opposed to relativistic expressions such as 2.18, it's only the positive frequency part that enters the expression? Or perhaps the question should be: what is the formal argument for the negative frequency part being present in the expression 2.18?

Answer (score 3):

The crucial difference is that (2.18) applies to a system whose Lagrangian and hence equation of motion (and solution set thereof) is invariant under $\phi\to\phi^\ast$, while (2.111) has no analogous $\psi\to\psi^\ast$ (or, in the spinor case, $\psi\to\psi^\dagger$) invariance. This extra discrete symmetry of relativistic field theory is the reason why it has a negative-frequency headache, and this is ultimately why a field interpretation that isn't just one particle's wavefunction is necessary; and, as Dirac realised from the spinor case (for which he found a first-order PDE), spin & antimatter come along as a consequence. If you look closely at which fields are (anti-)Hermitian, you can also realise the significance of the factor of $i$ in the momentum density of $\psi$.

Comment: I see. So how about complex relativistic scalar fields? These aren't invariant under $\psi \rightarrow \psi^*$ yet they have negative modes in their expansions; more than that - since the classical fields are complex, after quantization the operators aren't hermitian, so we use two different operators, not related by complex conjugation, like in expression 2.69, which eventually gives the interpretation of particles and anti-particles.

Comment: @Piotr It's not whether the fields are self-conjugate that's the issue here; it's whether, in the complex-field case, conjugation stays in the solution set. If you compare the TDSE to the Klein-Gordon equation, you'll see only the latter's solution set has this closure rule.

Comment: @J.G. Actually, I like your argumentation as I also had doubt about this question. Just only a little precision, I guess when it comes to the Dirac spinor case  the invariance you speak of is  $\psi \rightarrow \psi^c$ where $ \psi^c$ is the charge conjugation which is defined in its simplest way $\psi^c=\gamma^2 \psi^{*}$

Comment: @FredericThomas Well, yes, the Dirac equation is different again.